# Variable definition with condition without ternary operator

Tags: c, ansi-c

I just don't know what this line means.:

```
a = b%4 == 0 && b%100 != 0 || b%400 == 0;
```

Comment: If b is a year number, a is `true` if b is a leap year

Comment: You should give K&R a better read.

Comment: It means that the author is too incompetent and lazy to add sufficient brackets to make the expression clear to read and easy to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression would be more readable with extra parentheses:

```
a = ((b % 4 == 0) && (b % 100 != 0)) || (b % 400 == 0);
```

It is a test for leap year in the Gregorian calendar:

`b` is a leap year if it is a multiple of `4`, except if it is a multiple of `100`, or if it is a multiple of `400`.

As as example: `2016` is a leap year, `2000` was too, but `1900` was not and `2100` will not be a leap year.

The `||` and `&&` operators are shortcut logical operators, for respectively OR and AND conditions.  The expression is equivalent to this:

```
if (b % 4 == 0) {
    if (b % 100 != 0) {
        a = 1;
    } else {
        a = 0;
    }
} else {
    if (b % 400 == 0) {
        a = 1;
    } else {
        a = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A = true if

```
b%4 == 0
&&
b%100 !=0

OR

b%400 == 0
```

A = true if B is a leap year.
A = false if B is not a leap year.

We've had this 2 years ago :)

Comment: if I use relational operators A can be only 1/0? e.g.  "a = 2 * 4 == x" a will be 1 if x == 8?

Comment: Yes, A can only be False\True 0\1

Comment: a = 2*4 == x will be true if (x==8) and false if (x!=8);